Module installed but when script is executed says it is not installed
My script starts as follows:
from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toHexString

I have been developing using spyder and the script runs fine.
When I attempt to run at hyper command line, I get the following:
\smart.py", line 16, in <module>
    from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException        
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartcard'

When I check to see if pyscard is installed in the hyper environment, I get the following:
$ pip install pyscard
Requirement already satisfied: pyscard in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (2.0.10)

How can pyscard be installed and not be installed on execution?

In a nutshell: where pip installed the package and the Python installation hyper is using aren't the same Python installation.

Then why does it tell me it's installed when I query it's status in hyper?

How exactly are you doing all these things?

I open Spyder via hyper or anaconda.  The script sees pyscard and runs.  I run the script directly in hyper or anaconda and it says pyscard is not present.  I attempt to install pyscard in hyper or anaconda and it says it is installed.

Again: how exactly? Using the command line in hyper? Typing the commands pip install etc? If so, again, you probably have multiple Python installations on your machine and pip and python don’t refer to the same installation.

Ah, so pip and python (execution command) have different paths.  That a good tip, thanks

Downgrade your Python 3.11 to Python 3.8, and ensure you install swig to make psycard module work. It is a dependency issue you are facing and ensure that you upgraded your pip, mate.

Why would downgrading work?

that was how I solved my issue when I had the same problem. I have modified the answer a bit in case his error is attributed to not installing SWIG (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator) and VCCP (Visual C++ Express ) from Microsoft if he hasn't to make the module work. Sorry for replying to your comment late, I am a bit busy at work.
